# Prove trees has a leaf in set of vertices coloured black, or set of vertices coloured white

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that every tree has a leaf in the set of vertices coloured black, or the set of vertices coloured white, whichever has the larger cardinality (or both if they have equal size).

Any hints??

It's the second part of the question to proving trees are bipartite. I need hints for proving the leaf will be in the set with the higher cardinality or same if the sets have equal number.

Comment: It seems like this question needs more information added to it.

Comment: According to the song, all the leaves are brown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear to me whether you are allowed to use the fact that all trees are bipartite, or whether that is what you are trying to prove. I'll assume you can use the fact, that you have a partition of the vertices into two sets such that every edge connects a vertex in the one set with a vertex in the other, and you're trying to show that the bigger set contains a leaf. Let the two sets have $m$ and $n$ vertices, with $m\ge n$. If the $m$-set has no leaf, then every vertex in that set has degree at least $2$, so the number of edges in the graph is at least $2m$, which is at least $m+n$, which is the number of vertices. But then it's not a tree, since in a tree the number of edges is always one less than the number of vertices (another fact I assume you are allowed to use). Contradiction, we win.